# From which side does Klipa come?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

It says in some seforim, that Klipa "leeches" off the "right" side (since Gevura is about limitation, it can only give to one who is worthy, while Chesed, kindness, can give to everyone).

On the other hand, I've seen many places where Klipa is said to come from the left side.

How does this work out?

Comment: Maybe you can define better what 'klipa' is for all of us non-kabbalists.

Comment: Did you mean [_leach_](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leach#Verb) as you wrote, or [_leech_](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leech#Verb)?

Comment: Sources? Also, this sounds like a question for a Mashpia, not Judaism.SE

Comment: @HodofHod, why not here, more than any other question? Do you think it's [out of scope? not a real question? not constructive?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#close)

Comment: I would love to answer, maybe in the an email, but not here.

Comment: Anyways, please bring a source.

Comment: @msh210, none of the above. I _do_ think it is "unlikely to be answered properly here". I am not suggesting closing, merely that if Shmuel wants an answer, it would be better to ask an expert in Chassidus/Kabbalah.

Comment: It's a great question, but needs to be sourced.

Comment: @HodofHod, this is a long-tail question. It may or may not get an answer immediately, but hopefully, a relevant expert will come along and answer it at some point. I think it's worthwhile to post it here. It may be more likely to get a quicker answer in some other forum, but that doesn't mean it's not welcome here.

Comment: @HodofHod all the Halacha/Minhag tags should be addressed to a Rov.

Comment: @IsaacMoses True, and I don't say that it's unwelcome; merely that it might be better answered by an expert (my assumption being that Shmuel knows one). @ Shmuel, True, but that doesn't mean one won't get a useful or informative answer on Halacha here (even if it cannot be the final word). Questions on mysticism, on the other hand, seems to get less comprehensive answers.

Comment: In Tanya it says that Klippah comes from "Bechinat Achorayim", which is explained (among other things) as not wanted as an end, only as a means. Can you bring some sources for both statements in the question?

Answer (score 2):

Sefer Tanya by the Alter Rebbe discussions Klippah extensively. Klippah is spiritual shell that conceals G-dliness. There are 3 completely unclean klippos that have absolutely no good at all and must be stayed away from. ie: Non Kosher food. Then there is klippah nogah which has some good in it that needs to be extracted and elevated. ie: kosher food eaten for strength to serve Hashem.

Ch. 1 Introduces Klippah Ch.6 speaks of the levels of impurity Ch. 9 discusses how the Sitrah Achrah and Klippas Nogah comes from the Left side. In ch. 9 the Alter Rebbe introduces the two kings waring to capture the city. Your good inclination vs. your evil inclination trying to conquer the emotions of the heart.

These ideas and more are discussed in early Kabbalah, but the Alter Rebbe revolutionized the understanding of this through Tanya by laying out the concepts of Sitra Achra, Klippos, and a person ability to triumph over evil.

Practical Advice involving Klippos 
It says in the back of the Alter Rebbe's Likutei Torah on Parsha Kedoshim Maamar "Hadarta Pnei Zaken" in the name of the Friediker Rebbe that internalizing the first 12 chapters of Tanya will unite your soul levels of Nefesh Ruach and Neshamah. Then with Hashem's help you will triumph over sitra achra and klippa.

Comment: Klipa comes from the left. This has been sourced. What is your source that it can not leach off the left? Ch.6 of Tanya the Alter Rebbe quotes Kohelet 7:14. See Zohar III, 47b. that the 10 faculties of sitra d'kedushah also have an oppsoite in sitra d'achra. So there is a chesed, gevurah, tiferes, etc of kedusah and non kedusah. If the klippah comes from the left then leaching on the left would be leaching on itself. Please provide sources.

Comment: @mochinrechavim if you want to ShmuelBrill to see your comment, you must write @_____ whichever name you want.

Comment: Where exactly is this that you quote in the name of the Friediker Rebbe? I didn't find it in the section you quoted: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16093&st=&pgnum=89&hilite=

Comment: @ba It's in the back in Marei Mkomos for Parshas Kedoshim. Likutei Torah does not have added commentary by the Rebbeim dirrectly inside the maamarim. http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16093&st=&pgnum=712&hilite=

Answer (score -1):

The Klipa comes from the "left", as all "negative" and "chaotic" things do. It therefore, takes its "power" from the right side, but it "sits" on the left.

Comment: Source!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: The question is my source.  If all the information in the question is true, then my answer is the only possible answer.