# כחל of a Ḥayah Tehorah - same din as כחל of a Behemah Tehorah?

Tags: halacha, animals, meat-and-milk, parts-of-the-body

I'm trying to tighten up [my answer on Haman](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14962/5) and prepare for my Purim Derashah. Does anyone know if כחל of a Ḥayah Tehorah has the same Din as a Behemah Tehorah?

FYI, I want to change the words "Kosher animal" in that answer to "Behemah Tehorah", but I need to be 100% sure before I do. I'm just too tired now to connect all the dots to be totally sure of it. Are there any explicit sources?

Comment: I'm pretty sure because of [a Din mentioned within the answer](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&st=&pgnum=386) that the change is correct. Still, does anyone know of a source that explicitly states that the Din of כחל does not apply to a Ḥayah?

Comment: I guess "specifically" would be a better word than "explicitly". I'm still tired. Last night was a late night of writing and editing.

Comment: @Vram, I don't think it is the same. Meaning, the Heter is unnecessary. There's no Isur to begin with in cooking a Ḥayah with milk, and eating it is only DeRabanan. Maybe MiDeRabanan the Halachah is parallel to the Behemah, but I'm not sure why it should be so. See [the Din mentioned in that answer and above (and now here again)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&st=&pgnum=386).

Answer (score 1):

Woops! Sorry.

Rambam in [Hilchot Mamrim 2:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=90162&rid=14660) says the laws of milk & meat are biblically identical whether the animal is "domesticated" or "wild." Hence any rules regarding udder meat would be the same.

> יד  כיצד:  הרי כתוב בתורה "לא תבשל גדי, בחלב אימו" (שמות כג,יט; שמות לד,כו; דברים יד,כא).  ומפי השמועה למדו שזה הכתוב, אסר לבשל ולאכול בשר בחלב--בין בשר בהמה, בין בשר חיה; אבל בשר עוף, מותר בחלב מן התורה.

But as pointed out, Rambam elsewhere ([Ma'achalot Asurot 9:4](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/5209.htm)) & Mechaber say it's only rabbinic. Hm, good question!

But as far as I know the laws would be same.

Thanks everyone for correcting me!!

Comment: Who's "we"? [Clearly the Meḥaber holds differently](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&st=&pgnum=386).

Comment: The Rambam [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=5&hilchos=28&perek=9&halocha=4&hilite=) could not be any more explicit.

Comment: Whoa, Stira in the RaMBa"M?! The Sha"Ch (in my previous link) says RaMBa"M even admonishes and says it's Bal Tosif to say it is Asur MiDeOraitha ([last line of the Sha"Ch, S"K 4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&st=&pgnum=387)).

Comment: That is a famous stira in the Rambam, but everyone I know of solves the problem by "lav-davka"ing the Mamrim one. See Kesef Mishna in Mamrim for example.

Comment: Wait, RaMBa"M Hil. Mamarim? That's the same source in the Sha"Ch. Someone go get a hard copy of RaMBa"M, please. I'm at work.

Comment: @Vram I used Hebrewbooks because it has the kesef mishna available for viewing where he gives a similar but not identical answer to R Kapach.

Comment: Wow, that is a *HUGE* difference.

Comment: @Vram I just saw it a few minutes ago in [your link above](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14967/of-a-ayah-tehorah-same-din-as-of-a-behemah-tehorah/14970#comment28689_14970).

Comment: Is anyone else here exceptionally frustrated that Vram left and deleted his comments? I recall that this one was especially enlightening, but can't recall it (or its source) fully.

Comment: @SethJ Mods can see deleted comments. Perhaps if you ask politely for a specific one...

Comment: See [Avkat Rochel 38](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=636&pgnum=76)