# Non Jews and human flesh

Tags: sources-mekorot, kashrut-kosher, gentiles, noachide-laws, halacha-theory

There is a prohibition against a Jew eating human flesh. There is a dispute if it is a biblical or rabbinic prohibition  (see [here](http://www.torahmusings.com/2007/05/cannibalism), [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19071) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77375)). Either way, I'm wondering if a non jew has the same prohibition. If it's biblical, can we assume since its not one of the seven Noahides Laws they're exempt? Or according to [those who say it's one of the "mitzvos sichliot"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77377/1739),  a prohibition stemming from *svara*/logic, would they indeed be forbidden? If it's rabbinic, can we assume the Rabbis didn't meddle with non jews' diets? Is this discussed anywhere?

Comment: Not sure why there is an opinion that it's a Rabbinic prohibition when the Gemara (AZ 29b) provides a source for it. Presumably cannibalism would fall under defacing or benefiting from a human body.

Comment: By the way, just because something's not in the Sheva Mitzvos [doesn't mean they can do it](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77476/9682).

Comment: @DonielF your question prompted me to find the opinion. I linked to it; it's the Rosh. Regarding your second point, that's exactly why I asked this question.

Comment: @DonielF Actually the Gemara in Chulin (92, b) brings [shameless] cannibalism as one of the three Mitzvos out of thirty they still keep - according to Rashi's first understanding.                                                           שאין כותבין כתובה לזכרים ואחת שאין שוקלין בשר המת במקולין ואחת שמכבדין את התורה

Comment: @IrRelevant Gosh, I've been looking for that Gemara for years, in a completely unrelated context. Baruch atah lashamayim shehechezarta aveidasi.

Comment: The Aruch Hashulchan cites a number of Rishonim who held there is no prohibition on בשר אדם חי, including Raavad, Ramban, Rosh and Rashba. Yoreh Deah סימן עט
http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9106&st=&pgnum=358 is there any indication that these Rishonim hold that there is a Rabbinic prohibition?

Comment: If a noahide can’t eat the limb of a live animals, I assume he’ll be prohibited from consuming human flesh. It is forbidden. That is sick.

Comment: @TurkHill a Jew also can't eat the limb of a live animal, yet there are opinions that biblically it's permitted to eat human flesh

Comment: @robev Yes there are prohibitions. One is the prohibition to sacrifice human beings. Abraham’s near-sacrifice of Issac was a test.

Comment: @TurkHill what's your point? No one said anything about killing someone

Comment: @robev My point is that you cannot eat a living human. This prohibition is for Jews as well.

Comment: You claim “it’s biblically permitted to eat human flesh.” No, it is not. The opposite is true. Since the reverse is true, I am not responsible for what your sick or twisted mind comes up with in order to justify cannibalism

Comment: @TurkHill according to the Rosh, it is. If you disagree with him, that's not my problem. No one is talking about eating a live human

Comment: @robev Rambam said that some rabbis are wrong. Period. You cannot eat a live human. The only exception, maybe, is if you are starving and your dying friend begs you to consume him when he’s gone for your survival and even then, we should keep some decently, some dignity, and some civility. We are a civilized people.

Comment: @TurkHill did I say Rambam agreed? Your comments are unnecessary. And again, no one is talking about a live human. Let's talk about eating the dead skin on your lips. Is that uncivilized?

Answer (score 2):

[Shut Yad Elyahu (of Lublin) (45)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22182&st=&pgnum=121&hilite=) says that human flesh was never permitted to be eaten - either to Adam, nor Noah, nor their descendants.

Answer (score -2):

OK, so I'm a lurker/guest and this is an old post but I came across this post and it's not been answered directly.

I'm just going to point out that cannibalism IS prohibited to all men under the Noachide laws. 
Of the seven laws, the third law states: Do not murder.
And the sixth law states: Do not eat of a live animal.

So, where is this human meat coming from? Did you kill someone to get it? Because that is not permissible. Or, did you cut it off of a living person and then eat that? Because that is not permissible, either.

Now, you could possibly eat a human that died of natural causes if you really wanted to. 
However, the seventh law tells mankind to establish courts of justice and to ensure obedience.

In most developed countries, it's illegal to eat a corpse.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Chaya. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.
 Hope to see you around!

Comment: Certainly not covered by Noahide laws. Example: Gentile is in a life/death situation and must choose between eating human corpse or a limb taken off a live animal (by someone else).

Comment: The scenario you are referring to is covered in the comments here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77375/whats-a-better-choice-treif-meat-or-human-flesh?noredirect=1&lq=1
OP asked if it were prohibited. Yes, it is prohibited. There is always room for prohibitions for Jews and Gentiles alike to be circumvented due to extreme circumstances. However,  that was not the question

Comment: Welcome to MY. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Please consider [registering](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. Hope to see you around!

Comment: The OP asked “is this discussed anywhere?” If this is your own logic, this wouldn’t seem to address that, as the OP is looking for sources. If this is indeed sourced somewhere, would you please provide a source?

Comment: I thought it was obvious I was referring to meat from a dead person