# Does the prohibition of Gid Hanashe apply to human flesh?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, gid-hanashe

Regardless of how one holds re: "[Is human flesh a kosher food](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19071/is-human-flesh-a-kosher-food)?" (ie if **Yes**= legitimate question,
if **No**= additional *issur*)-

Would the prohibition of Gid Hanashe apply to human flesh?

Comment: Does it apply to non kosher animals?

Comment: It does not apply to tamei animals

Answer (score 6):

Yes ,according to the Rashba there is a prohibition of gid hanashe by a human. This is brought in the Mishneh Lamelech al HaRambam 8:1 .

Text of Mishneh Lemelech:

גיד הנשה נוהג בבהמה וחיה הטהורים. נ"ב איסור גיד הנשה נוהג אף באדם כ"כ הרשב"א סי' שס"ד יע"ש:

For further discussion see the Darkei Teshuva hilchos Dam 65 where there is a whole discussion about this.

Text of Darkei Teshuva:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the prohibition does not apply to human flesh. My reasoning is that it is not mentioned in the *Mishnah*, *Rambam*, or *Shulchan Aruch*. All that is mentioned is *beheimoh* and *chayoh* (kosher land animals) and the possibility of fowl. The prohibition does not apply to non-kosher animals. If it did apply to human flesh, which is not kosher, it should have been mentioned.

> **חולין פ"ט ב** :
> גיד הנשה וכו' ונוהג בבהמה ובחיה
> וכו' ואינו נוהג בעוף מפני שאין לו כף
>
> **רמב"ם הל' מאכלות אסורות ח:א, ד-ה** :
> גיד הנשה נוהג בבהמה וחיה הטהורין ואפי' בנבלות וטרפות שלהן
> וכו' העוף אין בו משום גיד הנשה מפני שאין לו כף ירך אלא יריכו ארוך ואם נמצא עוף שירכו כירך הבהמה שיש לו כף גיד הנשה שלו אסור ואין לוקין עליו
> וכו' האוכל גיד הנשה מבהמה וחיה הטמאים פטור לפי שאינו נוהג בטמאה אלא בבהמה שכולה מותרת
>
> **שו"ע יו"ד סה:ה** :
> גיד הנשה נוהג בבהמה וחיה וכו' ואינו נוהג בעוף מפני שאין כף שלו עגול אבל אם נמצא לו כף עגול נוהג בו

Comment: This is the reasonable response, but it is interesting to consider that the prohibition is based on specifically a human's tendon

Comment: The Chinuch sides with you