# What is the Halachic difference if people are kosher or not?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, machlokes, non-kosher-species

The Ramban derives that people are kosher from the gemara in Kerisos (21a i think) That since the rabbis said that human milk is kosher using concept that anything that comes from kosher animal is kosher. 
The Rosh, Rashba and Raavad agree. 
The Ramban holds humans aren't kosher since it says these you shall eat in Parshat Shmini. Therefore you violate a mitzvah asei. That's where the Ramban comments.

I was wondering what is the halachic difference if people are kosher or not. Since Ramban points out that you are not allowed to have pleasure from a dead body.

Comment: If a human body part falls into a pot of food - do you need 60 times that to be allowed to eat the food?

Comment: If you're on a desert island: What do you eat first?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19071/is-human-flesh-a-kosher-food and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17504/is-human-flesh-considered-fleishik

Comment: if should eat dead body over treif? It seems there are less Issurim but cmon a human? over trief?

Comment: @shlomo See page 6 https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:5QP22qVWDQIJ:www.edah.org/backend/JournalArticle/BRILL_5_2.pdf+&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgJpe1AsiMIH-b1krKp9cY5o9tHiUomzhICio_UdYrPTfxsxzj6fRn3a_D0zkLqnh83qklfZ7dCUPPLAeUraDc-ZoJt1kkkYbDoZh5B9gIHJfqStORgOrkst462QSKoYZCelj1n&sig=AHIEtbSkuZ0vWD4ug53ppIYVrPE6I4VMaw Similar sentiment can apparently be found in the hakdama [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/37184) but I haven't found the specific paragraph.

Comment: thank you its on the bottom paragraph on page 4. But According to the rema (79:1) eating human flesh is biblical prohibition right? And side Question you follow Rav Amital over Rav Shach?

Comment: Since at the time of writing, there wasn't much choice on what to feed infants, human milk not being kosher would be a bad thing indeed.

Comment: @shlomo I don't have a need for a general rule about how to choose between those two Talmidei Chachamim.