# What is this parsha about Haman and why should I read it daily?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

This morning, as I was about to put my tefillin bag in the closet, I saw a young guy still davening something after minyan was finished. I waited until he finished and asked him what he was saying. He told me he recites parshat Haman each day, and that it is very important that I should say it daily, too. I asked him why, and he said that reciting parshat Haman daily will improve my parnassa.

What is this guy talking about, and why or how can reading this parshat Haman improve my parnassa?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Related: _[Haman was Basar b’Chalav, so how could we eat him?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14923/70)_

Answer (score 4):

As you may know Haman was a very wealthy man. [He even gave the King 10,000 silver Kikars = 460 tons of silver](http://ohr.edu/holidays/purim/deeper_insights/glimpses_of_light/5732). Thus when one reads the Parsha of Haman he is praying for a piece of Haman's wealth. The reason it works is that Haman does not like when the Jews pray, as Jews prayers caused his downfall, thus he just gives of his wealth to anyone who says it in order to get them to stop.

Comment: Based on today's market price of approximately $15.50 per ounce of silver Haman gave the King 230 million dollars of silver.

Comment: +1. But I may have to revoke the vote if the price of silver decreases :-)

Comment: I know it's not very purimdik but I always check up on suspiciously large numbers in frum articles. I got 25.3 tons of silver according to the small shiur, and why would someone like haman follow the chazon ish?!

Answer (score 1):

Chazal say that the reason for the decree of Haman was twofold:

1. The Jewish people derived benefit from the feast of King Achashverosh, a symbol that they were loyal servants reliant on the economy of his kingdom.
2. The Jewish were corrupted by infighting and lashon harah.

When Mordechai rallied the Jews to fast, they displayed an unprecedented (in that generation) level of unity. It was in this merit that they were saved.

The young man is reading the ninth perek of Megillas Esther. It is called Parshat Haman because it deals with the retribution of the Jews against their aggressors and the final fall of the House of Haman. Of particular importance here is possuk 10:

> י**  עֲשֶׂרֶת  {ר}  בְּנֵי הָמָן בֶּן-הַמְּדָתָא, צֹרֵר הַיְּהוּדִים--הָרָגוּ; וּבַבִּזָּה--לֹא שָׁלְחוּ, אֶת-יָדָם**
>
> 10 the ten sons of Haman the son of Hammedatha, the Jews' enemy, slew they; ***but on the spoil they laid not their hand.***

This restraint was a rectification of their earlier sin at the feast of Achashverosh. Their refusal to despoil their fallen enemy was a declaration of faith that Hashem is the provider of all bounty.

The daily reading of this parsha is recommended as a reinforcement of both achdus and bitachon, and in the merit of these Hashem will grant us parnassa.

Answer (score 0):

Parshat Haman is a short parsha Esther 3:1 - 7. The parsha introduces Haman and the key part of this parsha refers to how the righteous Mordechai disobeyed the king's order to bow down to Haman.

The key verse is Esther 3:4:

> וַיְהִ֗י באמרם [כְּאָמְרָ֤ם] אֵלָיו֙ **י֣וֹם וָי֔וֹם** וְלֹ֥א שָׁמַ֖ע
>   אֲלֵיהֶ֑ם וַיַּגִּ֣ידוּ לְהָמָ֗ן לִרְאוֹת֙ הֲיַֽעַמְדוּ֙ דִּבְרֵ֣י
>   מָרְדֳּכַ֔י כִּֽי־הִגִּ֥יד לָהֶ֖ם אֲשֶׁר־ה֥וּא יְהוּדִֽי׃
>
> Now it came to pass, when they spoke **daily** unto him, and he hearkened
>   not unto them, that they told Haman, to see whether Mordecai’s words
>   would stand; for he had told them that he was a Jew.

From here, we learn that it was because the king's servants spoke to Mordechai **daily** and each day he refused to listen to them, that it was in this merit that Mordechai and the Jews were eventually spared. (Had it ben just a single or occasional warning, it would not have demonstrated Mordechai's merit as strongly.)

We see at the end of the Megillah, that Mordechai became wealthy as he was appointed vice minister to the king, and he wore royal garments, etc.

So this is why it is a good *segulah* to read this parshat Haman which refers to Mordechai's refusal to Haman.