# PTIJ: Why was Haman stored in a jar?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Gemara Yoma (52b) records

> והתניא משנגנז ארון נגנזה עמו צנצנת המן - when they buried the aron, they buried the jar of Haman with it.

I understand burying him, but why was he put in the jar in the first place?

Comment: There's no implication that Haman himself was placed in the jar. The term צנצנת המן only indicates that the jar belonged to him.

Comment: You don’t keep your hamentashen in a jar??

Comment: Previously on PTIJ (some answers there address this question as well): [How could the Jews eat Haman?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80889/), [Parshas Haman](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69210/), [Haman was Basar B'chalav](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14923/).

Comment: See Esther Rabbah intro #7

Answer (score 0):

I love it when another reader refers to one of my own questions! Thanks, @DonielF!

In my previous PTIJ question, [How could the Jews eat Haman](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80889/5275), I asked how the Jews were able to eat Haman for 40 years.

So, this explains how Haman stayed fresh for 40 years. He was vaccuum sealed in a jar!

Comment: I told you, it's the name. You said you're in Brooklyn, right? You should come to Queens sometime, we can enjoy some human tashen together as we ignore Talmud Torah.